# pandas.io.sql returnt that that table does not existst, even if it is existing

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

This is my code, I am running it on Windows XP, inside ipython notebook.

```
import os
os.getcwd() # This is current working directory 

db_path = '..\\06_django\\hzmo_web\\hzmo_web\\hzmo_backup_05_2013.db'


import sqlite3
from pandas.io import sql
# Create your connection.
cnx = sqlite3.connect('db_path')

cnx

cur = cnx.cursor()    
cur.execute('SELECT SQLITE_VERSION()')
data = cur.fetchone()
print "SQLite version: %s" % data 

import contextlib
with contextlib.closing(sqlite3.connect(db_path)) as conn:
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    cursor = conn.cursor()    
    cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
    for tablerow in cursor.fetchall():
        print tablerow[0]
        #table = tablerow[0]
        #cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {t}".format(t = table))
        #for row in cursor:
        #    for field in row.keys():
        #        print(table, field, row[field])

sql.read_frame('SELECT * FROM hzmo_report;', cnx)
```

I just want to select all data from hzmo_report table in pandas DataFrame, as I saw in documentation at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries

Error I get is that: OperationalError: no such table: hzmo_report
But that table does exist.

```
Here is output of my code:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-916237d66737> in <module>()
     29         #        print(table, field, row[field])
     30 
---> 31 sql.read_frame('SELECT * FROM hzmo_report;', cnx)
     32 

C:\Documents and Settings\hr1ub098\Application Data\Python\Python27\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.pyc in read_frame(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float)
    141         column name to use for the returned DataFrame object.
    142     """
--> 143     cur = execute(sql, con)
    144     rows = _safe_fetch(cur)
    145     columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cur.description]

C:\Documents and Settings\hr1ub098\Application Data\Python\Python27\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.pyc in execute(sql, con, retry, cur, params)
     33 
     34         if params is None:
---> 35             cur.execute(sql)
     36         else:
     37             cur.execute(sql, params)

OperationalError: no such table: hzmo_report

SQLite version: 3.6.21
auth_permission
auth_group_permissions
auth_group
auth_user_user_permissions
auth_user_groups
auth_user
django_content_type
django_session
django_site
django_admin_log
hzmo_report
Error on sql SELECT * FROM hzmo_report;
```

Does anybody have any idea what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cnx = sqlite3.connect('db_path')
```

Shouldn't that argument be the variable you created, not a string? In the above case you might be connecting to a new database named "db_path".

```
cnx = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. 
My question are becoming embarrassingly stupid. :-(